# How to create an ASP.NET Core Web API project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to develop a project, this project will be an ASP.NET Core project and in the project we will draw data from the API and convert this data into a certain format and save it to the database, but the information from the API needs to be automatically saved to the database.

How can I do this project, which pen should I get? I am open to any suggestions and information or if you can help me I would be very happy.

I know how to show the data coming from the API in the interface in ASP.NET Core, but how to save the data from the API directly to the database and when there is an API data update, the program should detect it directly and make this update in the database, I want to get information about it.

Comment: That's not how SO works. When you made an actual attempt at this that didn't work, come back and we'll have a look into it.

Comment: You should check [sql dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/755349/asp-net-core-5-0-signalr-with-sql-dependency).

Comment: Do you call the api periodically to get the update?